# Jquery - Getting a Total from Multiple Input Fields Without A Direct Input

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, sum

I've got a few fields the first being "shipment_details[charge]", which has the possibility of multiple rows of this very field. Now I've got it working to where I can get a subtotal of a multitude of these charges with the following script:

```
<script>
$(document).on('change', 'input[name^="shipment_details[charge][]"]', function() {
    var sum = 0.00;
    $('input[name^="shipment_details[charge][]"]').each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();  
    });
    $('input[name^="freightBillSubtotal"]').val(sum.toFixed(2));
});  
</script>
```

Where it inputs to freightBillSubtotal. And then I've got a separate portion of the page called "other_rate_amount". Now I've got a other_rate_total field which has it's value printed in when the "other_rate_amount" field is changed using the following script:

```
<script>
$(document).on('change', 'input[name^="other_rate_amount"]', function() {
    var sum = 0.00;
    $('input[name^="other_rate_amount"]').each(function(){
        sum += +$(this).val();  
    });
    $('input[name^="other_rate_total"]').val(sum.toFixed(2));
});  
</script>
```

But for the life of me, I can't get anything working to where an entirely separate field, named "total" is updated every time the "freightBillSubtotal" and "other_rate_total" are changed on account of their referring scripts.

### Update

This is the start of my JSFiddle, I'm not sure how to get the script to work in there to be honest, I've never made one myself there before: https://jsfiddle.net/uL5f7nxe/ - it should have all the aspects as to what I am referring to though.

Comment: You could try using `trigger` function like so `$('input[name^="total"]').trigger('change')`

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve]

Comment: Please provide a runnable test case http://jsonwrapper.com/

Comment: I've made the update with a link, the scripts aren't working there but only because I firmly believe it's how I formatted them on JSFiddle (never made one myself before, so sorry haha). I think all of the relevant details are there, all that needs to happen is the scripts to formatted correctly for it to actually work in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create another function to calculate total. Whenever there is change in either shipment charges or other rates change, call this function to calculate total. I have assumed that you want to add these two for total. Also added trigger to recalculate shipment subtotal when you remove a row.  Hope this helps..

```
        $(document).on('change', 'input[name^="other_rate_amount"]', function() {
        var sum = 0.00;
        $('input[name^="other_rate_amount"]').each(function(){
            sum += +$(this).val();  
        });
        $('input[name^="other_rate_total"]').val(sum.toFixed(2));
        calcTotal();
    });  

    $(document).on('change', 'input[name^="shipment_details[charge][]"]', function() {
        var sum = 0.00;
        $('input[name^="shipment_details[charge][]"]').each(function(){
            sum += +$(this).val();  
        });
        $('input[name^="freightBillSubtotal"]').val(sum.toFixed(2));
        calcTotal();
    });  

    function calcTotal() {
        var otherRate = $('input[name^="other_rate_total"]').val();
        var subTotal = $('#freightBillSubtotal').val();
        var total = parseFloat(otherRate) + parseFloat(subTotal);
        console.log(total);
        $('#total').val(total);
    }

     $(document).ready(function(){  
          var i=1;  
          $('#add').click(function(){  
               i++;  
               $('#freight_bill_items').append('<tr id="row'+i+'"> <td style="width:8%;text-align:center;"><input type="text" name="shipment_details[piecesNumber][]" class="form-control name_list" id="piecesNumber" placeholder="No. Pieces"></td><td style="width:16%;text-align:center;"><select style="width:100%; display:inline" class="form-control" name="shipment_details[piecesType][]" id="pieces_type"><option selected value="">Please select</option>     @foreach($piecetypes as $piecetype)<option value="{{ $piecetype->id }}">{{ $piecetype->label }}</option>@endforeach</select></td><td><select style="width:100%; display:inline" class="form-control" name="shipment_details[rateType][]" id="rateType">option selected value="">Please select</option>     @foreach($ratetypes as $ratetype)<option value="{{ $ratetype->id }}">{{ $ratetype->label }}</option>@endforeach</select></td><td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;"><input type="text" name="shipment_details[weight][]" id="weight" class="form-control name_list" placeholder="Weight"></td><td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;"><select style="width:100%; display:inline" class="form-control" name="shipment_details[hazmat][]" id="hazmat">                    <option selected value="0">No</option><option value="1">Yes</option></select></td><td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;"><input type="text" name="shipment_details[description][]" class="form-control name_list" placeholder="Description" id="description"></td><td style="width:16.5%;text-align:center;"><input type="text" name="shipment_details[charge][]" class="form-control name_list" placeholder="Charge" id="charge"></td><td><button type="button" name="remove" id="'+i+'" class="btn btn-danger btn_remove">X</button></td></tr>');  
          });  
          $(document).on('click', '.btn_remove', function(){  
               var button_id = $(this).attr("id");   
               $('#row'+button_id+'').remove();  
               $( 'input[name^="shipment_details[charge][]"]' ).trigger( "change" );
          });
    });
```

Comment: Thank you thank you so much for your assistance! This worked great!